# Change the body of a request

Tags: java, servlets, request

I have a Java Servlet, which is handling a REST request.  However, this is breaking when it receives invalid data.  This is POSTed in XML format, and to attempt to resolve this I have added a filter into the filter chain.  The filter is being called, and I can access the data in the body of the request, accessing the XML.

I can validate this and manipulate it to ensure that the data is correct, but I cannot work out how to reset it back into the request object.

How can you set the body of an HttpServletRequest object?

Comment: Could you please help me to understand how did you update the request data i.e HTTP POST data and set it back to request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap Your HttpServletRequest object with a new class lets name it: NewHttpServletRequest. The actual rewriting should be done in the appropriate overriden methods e.g getParameter(String)

```
package com.example;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper;

public class MyHttpServletRequest extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    public MyHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    public String getParameter(String name) {
        String str = super.getParameter(name);
        // DO THE REWRITING
        return str;
    }
```

}

Comment: Could you please share your code to rewrite the request /.

Answer (score 2):

Take  look at [HttpServletRequestWrapper](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html)

You can wrap original request with a new object by using [public HttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html#HttpServletRequestWrapper%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest%29) constructor, you won't have to do a lot work yourself.